# Change $scope value when a ng-click function is triggered

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

I tried to change a $scope variable in [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) `ng-click` function. But [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs)does not seem to be able to do that.

Below is my code on my `appController`:

```
//  appController.js

$scope email = "Awesome@example.com";

$scope.emailInfo = "great@example.com";

//emailOnClick() is a ng-click on DOM. It will be triggered when the user click a button, which is to save his email information

$scope.emailOnClick = function() {

  $scope.email = $scope.emailInfo;

  console.log($scope.email); //this will print "great@example.com".

};

console.log($scope.email); // this will print "awesome@example.com", but I 

//want it to print "great@example.com" as I triggered the ng-click function to 

//apply the change.


console.log($scope.emailInfo); //this will print "great@example.com".
```

What do I miss?  Any thought?

Comment: it's not exactly clear what you are trying to do here.  Where **exactly** in your code is this "global variable" assigned, and why are you trying to do this in the first place? global variables are never a good thing.

Comment: Your defining a click event, not running it.

Comment: Try debugging by starting off `$scope.emailInfo` in your controller with a default value that is not `''`, something like `test@aol.com` and place that binding somewhere on the page. Once you click, see if it changes it.

Comment: ok now you changed the context of the question *entirely*.  Before, you weren't using `$scope`, and you received answers stating that you should, so changing your question to inject `$scope` will make this question and associated answers **very** confusing to others in the future.  aside from that, the first line of code, `$scope email` isn't even right (*perhaps* the absence of the `.` is a typo in the edit).

Comment: also, this isn't really a complete example.  You don't show where these `console.log` messages are triggered, you don't show which controller these `$scope` variables are declared in, and you don't show the HTML that triggers this function.  If those `console.log` messages are truly just in the base of the controller function, then it makes sense that they output the value that is set at the beginning, since they will output **LONG** before the function gets invoked.

Comment: @Claies Agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated:**

`$scope.emailOnClick` function will assign the `$scope.emailInfo` value to the `$scope.email` variable.

If you click in the «Send to server» button you'll see the new value that has been sent in the console.

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
  app.controller("Controller", ["$scope",
    function($scope) {
      $scope.email = "Awesome@example.com";
      $scope.emailInfo = "great@example.com";
      $scope.emailOnClick = function() {
        $scope.email = $scope.emailInfo; // Gets emailInfo value and assigns to $scope.email.
        console.log($scope.email);
      }
      $scope.sendToServer = function() {
        console.log($scope.email);
      };
      console.log($scope.email); // Initial state of $scope.email printed by default.
      console.log($scope.emailInfo); // Initial state of $scope.emailInfo printed by default.
    }
  ]);
})();
```

```css
.email {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#FFF, #CCC);
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
.emailInfo {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#FFF, #FBEE95);
  border: solid 1px #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
.option-clicked {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="myApp">
  <div data-ng-controller="Controller">
    <div class="email">email: <span class="option-clicked">great@example.com</span>

    </div>
    <div class="emailInfo">emailInfo: <span class="option-clicked">{{email}}</span>

    </div>
    <button data-ng-click="emailOnClick()">Get email</button>
    <button data-ng-click="sendToServer()">Send to the server</button>
    <br />Result:
    <input id="txtEmail" data-ng-model="email" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've made a simple demo http://jsfiddle.net/dannyjhonston/8y4h6zx0/
Can you check it out?

Comment: Yes, I define  $scope.email = "awesome@example.com" outside the ng-click function emailOnclick . When ng-click function is triggered, value of $scope.email will change to "great@example.com" and printed on the console. However, if I put console.log($scope.email) outside of the ng-click, it turned back to its original value. I am wondering if there is a way to change the value of $scope.email in a ng-click function.

Comment: @Brother_MW I've updated my answer with more details about your requirement. Can you check it out? Check the console when you run the example.

Comment: Will those two console.logs on the last two lines print the same email address after those ng-clicks are triggered? I want them to print the same output as we have used ng-click function to make changes.@Danny Fardy Jhonston Bermúdez

Comment: No, because they are within the same context within the same scope where you initialize $scope.email and $scope.emailInfo variables. This result is correct within the execution time of the controller. However, in this demo, when you execute the emailOnClick function you'll see the new values that has been updated in the view. Finally, when you execute the sendToServer function you'll see the new value that has been sent. This behaviour is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a click function. Try moving your `console.log` inside the:

```
$scope.emailOnClick = function() {
```

Comment: But I want it to be able to get the value after ng-click so that I can pass "var email" to the server later on.